# Функция возвращает неправильное значение

Tags: c, ассемблер

Компилирую в Visual Studio 2015 64 битную программу, в ней два файла:

2.asm

```
.code
;--------------------------------------------
Addup PROC, Arg1:DWORD, Arg2:DWORD, Arg3:DWORD
mov eax, Arg1
add eax, Arg2
add eax, Arg3
ret
Addup ENDP
;----------------------------------------------
END
```

1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int __stdcall Addup(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << Addup(1, 1, 1);
    system("pause");
}
```

Проблема в том, что вместо правильного значения 3, программа выводит какой-то мусор:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить? Заранее благодарен.

Решение:

Вот тут: msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335933.aspx ответ:

> В x64-соглашении первые четыре целочисленных аргумента (слева направо) передаются в 64-битных регистрах, предназначенных специально для этой цели: RCX: 1-й целочисленный аргумент RDX: 2-й целочисленный аргумент R8: 3-й целочисленный аргумент R9: 4-й целочисленный аргумент Остальные целочисленные аргументы передаются через стек.

2.asm

```
.code
;--------------------------------------------
Addup PROC

mov rax, rcx
add rax, rdx
add rax, r8

ret
Addup ENDP
;----------------------------------------------
END
```

Comment: Я бы посмотрел под дизассемблером, что за код в итоге получается. Скорее всего при компиляции под x64 используется какой-то "особый" stdcall.

Comment: Есть ничем не подкреплённое подозрение, что в 64-битной модели значение возвращается в RAX, а у вас его верхняя часть здесь находится в неопределённом состоянии.

Comment: Поменял все eax на rax, тип параметров функции заменил на qword, тоже самое.

Comment: Вот тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335933.aspx ответ: "В x64-соглашении первые четыре целочисленных аргумента (слева направо) передаются в 64-битных регистрах, предназначенных специально для этой цели:
RCX: 1-й целочисленный аргумент
RDX: 2-й целочисленный аргумент
R8: 3-й целочисленный аргумент
R9: 4-й целочисленный аргумент
Остальные целочисленные аргументы передаются через стек."

Comment: @user310775, добавьте ваше решение как ответ, вместе с цитатой из msdn

Comment: @user310775, как ответ - это не в вопрос, а в поле "Ваш ответ" под вопросом.

Comment: `gcc -S ...` дает ассемблерный код сишного текста. Очень советую поизучать код, который делает компилятор.

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

Вот тут: msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335933.aspx ответ:

> В x64-соглашении первые четыре целочисленных аргумента (слева направо) передаются в 64-битных регистрах, предназначенных специально для этой цели: RCX: 1-й целочисленный аргумент RDX: 2-й целочисленный аргумент R8: 3-й целочисленный аргумент R9: 4-й целочисленный аргумент Остальные целочисленные аргументы передаются через стек.

2.asm

```
.code
;--------------------------------------------
Addup PROC

mov rax, rcx
add rax, rdx
add rax, r8

ret
Addup ENDP
;----------------------------------------------
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте для 2.asm указать .model в духе

```
.MODEL FLAT,  STDCALL
```

Comment: Пробовал, тогда не компилируется, пишет: syntax error : .

Comment: В началефайла добавляли отдельной строкой?

Comment: Совершенно верно. В x86 работает, в x64 ругается на .model

Comment: Попробуйте выставить правильн опции для асм может быть: https://habr.com/post/252647/ начиная от " создаем *.asm файл". У меня компайлется: https://i.imgur.com/v7xsZ0V.png

Comment: @FLCL в статье в 32-битный код компилируется, в вопросе явно указано, что нужно собрать 64-битную программу.

Comment: Вы под x86 или под x64 собирали? Если я собираю под x86, тогда тоже все работает, проблемы начинаются если пробовать собрать 64 разрядную программу.